# radio button is selecting multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Quiz.css"> 
<script>
    var xmlh,url;

    xmlh = new XMLHttpRequest();
    url="AnswerFile.txt";

    xmlh.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlh.readyState == 4 && xmlh.status ==200){
        var myArr =JSON.parse(xmlh.responseText);
        myFunctuion(myArr);
      }
    };
    xmlh.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlh.send();
    function myFunctuion(arr){
        var dom=document.getElementById("demo");
        var cha=document.getElementById("radio1");
        var chb=document.getElementById("radio2");
        var chc=document.getElementById("radio3");
        dom.innerHTML = "<h3>" +arr[0].question+ "</h3>";
        cha.innerHTML = arr[0].ChA  ;
        chb.innerHTML = arr[0].ChB ;
        chc.innerHTML = arr[0].ChC ;

    }
</script>
<head>
<html>
<body>
<div class="w3-content" >
<form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-label">
<label id="demo"></label>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="ChA" value="a"> <label id="radio1"></label></input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="ChB" value="b"><label id="radio2"></label> </input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="ChC" value="c"> <label id="radio3"></label></input></br>
<br>
<br>
<input  class="w3-btn w3-xlarge w3-dark-grey w3-hover-light-grey w3-center w3-section w3-border w3-round-xlarge " style="font-weight:900;" type="submit" value="Submit Answers">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i get my all question and option from text file by JSON and i succeeded it .
But my main problem is all my radio button is checked where i want to if one button is checked then other button is unchecked .
what my problem in code ? what i do? and why cause this problem ?
?** for style i use W3.CSS **?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML input radio should have the same name attribute, like this:

```
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="a"> <label id="radio1"></label></input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="b"><label id="radio2"></label> </input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="c"> <label id="radio3"></label></input></br>
```

Comment: Beat me to it, nice <3

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons should all use the same name :)

```
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="a"> <label id="radio1"></label></input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="b"><label id="radio2"></label> </input></br>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="Ch" value="c"> <label id="radio3"></label></input></br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of your radio input fields should be same for specific question's options. Like below:

**First group of radios**

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="radopt1" id="radopt1"><label for="radopt1">Radio Option1</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="radopt2" id="radopt2"><label for="radopt2">Radio Option2</label> </input>
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="radopt3" id="radopt3"><label for="radopt3">Radio Option3</label></input>
```

**Second group of radios**

```
<input type="radio" name="rad1" value="rad1opt1" id="rad1opt1"><label for="rad1opt1">Radio1 Option1</label></input>
<input type="radio" name="rad1" value="rad1opt2" id="rad1opt2"><label for="rad1opt2">Radio1 Option2</label> </input>
<input type="radio" name="rad1" value="rad1opt3" id="rad1opt3"><label for="rad1opt3">Radio1 Option3</label></input>
```